# Can't access certain HTTPS sites on Firefox 3.6

Tags: firefox, centos, https

I have an old box that has been running for many many years, and has been functioning as a monitoring box (i.e there are a load of tv's connected to it, and on those, there are many web pages showing readouts).

This box is running CentOS 6.2, and due to the hardware configuration, seems only compatible with Firefox, and the latest version available from the repositories is Firefox 3.6.

So far, I have dozens of screens, and they are entirely HTTP at the moment, however, I now want to put (just starting with) an Outlook.com window on there (I use outlook as an example, all the others seem to have the same issue). When I navigate to the site (via HTTPS), I get the login form (the same is true of other sites), but when I try to login, I get a request timeout. Refreshing (without submitting) the page just brings me back to where I began.

Can someone enlighten me as to what is happening with Firefox that is preventing it from interacting with these pages?

Comment: If I were to guess.  The version of Firefox you are using is attempting to use a SSL/TLS connection the server is out right rejecting.

Comment: @Ramhound yeah, i was thinking perhaps missing a specific cipher suite, perhaps one of the one-time-use ciphers

Comment: You will have to investigate that, but if its a software capability issue, then you might be out of luck.

Comment: @Ramhound DAMMIT! well, will continue to investigate, and if luck strikes, i'll be back here!! Until then, probably a local web scraper is needed...

Comment: It appears that it is not a case of cipher suites. I have just installed a fresh copy of RHEL 6.2 on a test machine, and have tested the sites and they work fine